# draw cell borders using heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I'm trying to make a heatmap using `heatmap.2` but I don't get a cell border. If I set the parameter `sepwidth` and `sepcolor` it does not work, I have to include the `colsep` and `rowsep` parameters but still doing that, some cell borders are not drawn, any ideas?

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(df), key=F, trace="none", ColSideColors=colorside, 
                         cexRow=0.6, breaks=bk1, col=colors2, 
                         lmat=rbind(c(0,0), c(0,4), c(0,1), c(3,2), c(0,0)),
                         lhei=c(0.4,0.3,0.05,0.4,0.6), 
                         sepwidth=c(0.01, 0.01), sepcolor="black", 
                         colsep=1:length(df), rowsep=1:length(df))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It appears your problem is with the `colsep` and `rowsep` arguments. From the help file:

> `colsep, rowsep, sepcolor`  (optional) vector of integers indicating
>   which columns or rows should be separated from the preceding columns
>   or rows by a narrow space of color `sepcolor`

Instead of "indicating which columns or rows should be separated", your code creates a vector as long as the number of elements in the matrix. If you had set `colsep=c(1,3)`, the separator between the 1st and 2rd columns and the separator between the 3rd and 4th columns would have been colored. I don't believe there is a way to color the cell borders without using the `colsep` and `rowsep` arguments. The cell borders are, by default, not drawn unless these arguments are given values.

```
# First, a reproducible data set
library(gplots)
mat = matrix( rnorm(100), ncol=5 )
colorside = gray(1:5/5)
bk1 = seq(min(mat),max(mat),length.out=11)
col = redgreen(10)

# And now the heatmap
heatmap.2( mat, 
           key=FALSE, 
           trace="none",
           ColSideColors=colorside,
           cexRow=0.6,
           breaks=bk1,
           col=col,
           sepwidth=c(0.1,0.1),
           sepcolor="purple",
           colsep=1:ncol(mat),
           rowsep=1:nrow(mat))
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is a limit to the sepwidth keyword so as I cant make it very tiny. Any idea?

Answer (score -4):

set 
    heatmap.2(as.matrix(df), key=F, trace="both"  ...